# Why finding Elbow (or using L-method) with CH and SIL for number of cluster selection?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

In [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0038092X14000395), the author uses CH (Caliński–Harabasz index) and SIL (Silhouette index) methods to decide  the number of clusters. However, instead of selecting the highest values, it applies a L-method on these index, choosing its knee (elbow) points.
[image]

[In this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242360/dendrogram-in-hybrid-hierarchical-clustering-and-cut-off-criterion-calinski-har) there are many subquestions, in which one is about why the authors use the maximal 'stability' of CH to define the number of clusters. However, there wasn't a answer for this subquestion that has explained that decision.

The maximal 'stability' on that question is related with the L-method as they chose points where the changes start to be the smallest.

What could be the reason for using the L-method (or the maximal stability) with CH and SIL indexes, which usually are wanted to me maximized? (I would understand if they would be using the within sum of squares, for instance)

Comment: Not a programming question, hence arguably off-topic here; consider moving it to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I do not see how this approach could make sense (and people publish a lot of garbage!) - obviously the silhouette of 0.3 is all but good. In other words, their clustering failed, and now they make it worse. The easiest way to get "stability" is of course a bad result, as bad as random. They probably didn't look at the result much, just playing with these plots.

Answer (score 1):

A common problem with cluster analysis is that people are pre-set in that there *must* be a good clustering, and that it *must* be achievable with their preprocessing, method, and parameters. **Failing to cluster clearly was not an option - but it should have been**. In particular if you (have to) do a lot of preprocessing, this can easily fail. Apply PCA on complex enough data, and all you will get is a *single* Gaussian-like blob. The biggest mistake in statistics is that you don't test if maybe your entire hypothesises are all wrong...

You can find successful CH  and Silhouette plots for example here:

https://mathworks.com/help/stats/clustering.evaluation.calinskiharabaszevaluation-class.html

https://mathworks.com/help/stats/clustering.evaluation.silhouetteevaluation-class.html

The plot indicates that on the -very well-behaved- Iris data, 3 clusters is likely the better choice. This is what a CH respectively Silhouette plot should look like *if* you want to use it to argue about the number of clusters. If the plot doesn't show such a peak, then you probably cannot use it - or all of your clusterings are bad...

It should also be noted that these measures are just heuristics. A better CH or Silhouette does *not* guarantee a better result for every purpose.

Comment: If cluster is used only to reduce the number of elements into a smaller number of representative elements (not variables, as PCA does) that aren't necessarily very distinct, then, couldn't cluster analisys be useful even with bad Indexes (which would be due to the hight similarity between clusters)? I think that was the goal in the paper (albeit they have use these indexes in a wrong way).

Comment: If the index doesn't measure what you need, then don't use it.  Use SSQ where the "elbow" approach makes some sense: you'd stop when the gain in SSQ reduction becomes disproportionally small (while the costs increase). But why on Earth would you choose k such that it stops getting *worse* when it's already really bad?

Comment: To me that just says they didn't understand the difference between SSQ, CH, and Silhouette, and just glued together random approaches without considering the theoretical support or implications of what they are doing...